# How do I always stream my music using the VLC gui?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, streaming

I stream my music to a networked computer that is connected to my stereo.  The desktop computer I am using has VLC and I prefer to use the GUI.  Unfortunately, every time I add something, I have to go through the network streaming wizard.

Is there a fast way to say "always stream everything and don't play locally"?

I am using RTP unicast with no transcoding if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do so using the native GUIs; I'm pretty sure it's impossible. However, giving up using the native GUIs and switching to something with VLM fits your usage case.

VLM is available in HTTP and telnet, but I'd say the HTTP interface ends up being less usable than the telnet.

The good news is you could write a GUI using Lua that interfaces with VLM, or write something in whatever language you like to interface with the telnet server. In any case, I think VLM's your best bet.